# Room: SQLite_ERROR SQL error or missing database (no such table: )

Tags: android, android-room, entity-relationship

I'm trying to establish a entity relationship with the room library in android.

In this particular case I have an Event which can be a part of multiple EventRatings, while an EventRating only has 1 Event (1-to-n relationship as far as I understood).
I created an EventWithEventRatings class for retrieving all EventRatings with one specific Event.
For the sake of completeness: There is an analogue UserWithEventRatings class for filtering by User.

With this configuration I am getting the following warning / errors regarding the automatically generated EventsWithEventRatings.java class:

```
...\data\relations\EventWithEventRatings.java:18: warning: The affinity of parent column (id : INTEGER) does not match the type affinity of the child column (event : TEXT).
    private final java.util.List<...data.eventrating.EventRating> eventRatings = null;
                                                                                             ^
...\data\relations\EventWithEventRatings.java:18: error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: EventRating)
    private final java.util.List<...data.eventrating.EventRating> eventRatings = null;
                                                                                             ^
...\data\relations\EventWithEventRatings.java:18: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (...data.eventrating.EventRating).
    private final java.util.List<net.jochenbauer.healthrec2023.data.eventrating.EventRating> eventRatings = null;
```

Lines 12-18 of EventWithEventRatings.java

```
public final class EventWithEventRatings {
    @androidx.room.Embedded
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
    private final ...data.event.HrEvent event = null;
    @androidx.room.Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "event")
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
    private final java.util.List<...data.eventrating.EventRating> eventRatings = null;
```

HrEvent class:

```
@Entity
data class HrEvent(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var name: String
)
```

EventDao:

```
@Dao
interface HrEventDao {

    @Upsert
    suspend fun upsert(hrEvent: HrEvent)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(hrEvent: HrEvent)

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM HrEvent WHERE id = :eventID")
    suspend fun getEventWithEventRatings(eventID: Int): List<EventWithEventRatings>

}
```

EventRating class:

```
@TypeConverters(MyTypeConverter::class)
@Entity
data class EventRating(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    var date: Date,
    var value: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user")
    var user: User,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event")
    var event: HrEvent
) {...}
```

EventWithEventRatings class:

```
@TypeConverters(MyTypeConverter::class)
data class EventWithEventRatings(
    @Embedded
    val event: HrEvent,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "event"
    )
    val eventRatings: List<EventRating>
)
```

EventRatingDatabase class:

```
@Database(entities = [EventRating::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(MyTypeConverter::class)
abstract class EventRatingDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val dao: EventRatingDao

    class Callback @Inject constructor(
        private val database: Provider<EventRatingDatabase>,
        @ApplicationScope private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope
    ) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)

            val dao = database.get().dao

            applicationScope.launch {
                // Inserting default event ratings here
                println("Inserting default user data")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppModule class providing dependency injection for the databases and Daos:

```
...

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideEventRatingDatabase(
    app: Application,
    callback:EventRatingDatabase.Callback
) = Room.databaseBuilder(app, EventRatingDatabase::class.java, EVENT_RATING_DATABASE)
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .addCallback(callback)
    .build()

...
```

This is the TypeConverter I'm using:

```
class MyTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromDate(date: Date?): Long? {
        return date?.time
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toDate(time: Long?): Date? {
        return if (time != null) Date(time) else null
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromHrEvent(event: HrEvent): String {
        return event.name
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toHrEvent(eventName: String): HrEvent {
        return HrEvent(id = 0, name = eventName)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromUser(user: User?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(user)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toUser(userString: String?): User? {
        val type = object : TypeToken<User>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(userString, type)
    }
}
```

I tried defining an explicit name for the Annotated @Entity-class EventRating to address the "missing database"-error.

Answer (score 0):

---

**Issue 1 - No Such Table**

---

Your first issue is that you are only defining a single entity to the database when you specify `@Database(entities = [EventRating::class], version = 1)`

As such the database will only have the one table not the expected two tables. You need to define all the tables (entities). So you would want to have:-

```
@Database(entities = [HrEvent::class, EventRating::class], version = 1)
```

- i.e. Define the `@Entity` annotated **HREvent** class so that it is recognised as a table in the database and thus resolve the `There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: EventRating) private final java.util.List<...data.eventrating.EventRating> eventRatings = null;` issue.

---

**Issue 2 - Type Mismatch**

---

The `EventWithEventRatings.java:18: warning: The affinity of parent column (id : INTEGER) does not match the type affinity of the child column (event : TEXT). private final java.util.List<...data.eventrating.EventRating> eventRatings = null;` issue is due to a mismatch between then **HREvent**'s **id** column and the **EventRating**'s **event** column. The former is an integer, the latter is a JSON String.

When it comes to a relationship you are saying something along the lines of this value refers to the other value, which must obviously be of the same type. You issue appears to be based upon a misconception that you can refer to part of a Type Converted value. You cannot (at least simply).

The solution is to change the column type in the **EventRating** to be the same type as the parent **HREvent**, an **Int** not a Type Converted version of the entire parent HREvent. So:-

```
@Entity
data class EventRating(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    var date: Date,
    var value: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user")
    var user: User,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event")
    var event: Int /*<<<<<<<<<< now Int, was an Type Converted HrEvent (JSON String) */
)
```

---

**Issue 3 - Not Sure How to Convert (aka no Type Converter)**

---

This issue is fixed by the previous fix as the event field is no longer a type of HrEvent but is instead an Int type.

As there is now no embedded (replication) of the parent HREvent in the EventWithRating then there is no need for the Type Conversion of the HREvent and this the elimination of the `...\data\relations\EventWithEventRatings.java:18: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (...data.eventrating.EventRating). private final java.util.List<net.jochenbauer.healthrec2023.data.eventrating.EventRating> eventRatings = null;` issue.

---

**Demo**

---

Using the following code (adapted for convenience and brevity, no Type Converters, ability to run on the Main Thread and not using injections etc):-

```
@Entity
data class HrEvent(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var name: String
)

@Entity
data class EventRating(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    var date: String /* Date - changed to String for the demo. so no need for Type Converter*/,
    var value: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user")
    var user: String /* User - changed to String for the demo, so no need for User Class and Type Converter*/,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event")
    var event: Int /* HrEvent */
)

data class EventWithEventRatings(
    @Embedded
    val event: HrEvent,
    @Relation(
        entity = EventRating::class, /* suggested to always specify the class even though not always needed */
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "event"
    )
    val eventRatings: List<EventRating>
)

@Dao
interface HrEventDao {
    @Upsert
    /*suspend*/ fun upsert(hrEvent: HrEvent): Long
    @Insert
    fun insert(eventRating: EventRating): Long

    @Delete
    /*suspend*/ fun delete(hrEvent: HrEvent)

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM HrEvent WHERE id = :eventID")
    /*suspend*/ fun getEventWithEventRatings(eventID: Int): /*List<*/EventWithEventRatings/*> LIST not really need as should only return 1 eventwitheventratings*/
}

@Database(entities = [HrEvent::class, EventRating::class], version = 1)
abstract class EventRatingDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val dao: HrEventDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: EventRatingDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): EventRatingDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,EventRatingDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for convenience and brevity */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as EventRatingDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

And then with the following activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: EventRatingDatabase
    lateinit var dao: HrEventDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = EventRatingDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.dao

        val e1 = dao.upsert(HrEvent(0,"Event1"))
        val e2 = dao.upsert(HrEvent(0,"Event2"))
        val e3 = dao.upsert(HrEvent(100,"Event3"))

        dao.insert(EventRating(0,"A date",10,"Fred",e1.toInt()))
        dao.insert(EventRating(0,"A date",10,"Mary",e1.toInt()))
        dao.insert(EventRating(0,"A date",10,"Jane",e1.toInt()))
        dao.insert(EventRating(0,"A date",10,"Bert",e1.toInt()))

        dao.insert(EventRating(0,"A date",10,"Dref",e2.toInt()))
        dao.insert(EventRating(0,"A date",10,"Yram",e2.toInt()))

        logEWR(e1)
        logEWR(e2)
        logEWR(e3)

    }

    fun logEWR(eventId: Long) {
        val ewr = dao.getEventWithEventRatings(eventId.toInt())
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (er in ewr.eventRatings) {
            sb.append("\n\tRating is ${er.value} by ${er.user} on ${er.date}")
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO","Event is ${ewr.event.name} with an ID of ${ewr.event.id}. It has ${ewr.eventRatings.size} ratings. They are:-${sb}")
    }
}
```

When run then the result output to the log is:-

```
2023-07-15 07:24:16.259 D/DBINFO: Event is Event1 with an ID of 1. It has 4 ratings. They are:-
        Rating is 10 by Fred on A date
        Rating is 10 by Mary on A date
        Rating is 10 by Jane on A date
        Rating is 10 by Bert on A date
2023-07-15 07:24:16.268 D/DBINFO: Event is Event2 with an ID of 2. It has 2 ratings. They are:-
        Rating is 10 by Dref on A date
        Rating is 10 by Yram on A date
2023-07-15 07:24:16.272 D/DBINFO: Event is Event3 with an ID of 100. It has 0 ratings. They are:-
```

i.e. as expected the 3 Events. The first Event1 having the 4 ratings, event2 having 2 ratings and Event3 having 0 ratings.

And as can be seen there is no need to embed (Type Convert) the parent HREvent within an EventRating. All that is needed for the relationship is a value that uniquely identifies the parent (HREvent) of the child (EventRating).

Using the above (without Type Converters) the database, show using **App Inspection**, has the 2 tables (the room_master table is a Room system table and can effectively be ignored):-

**HrEvent** which has data as per:-

[image]

**EventRating** which has data as per:-

[image]

The important thing to note is the **event** column in the **EventRating** it is simply the **id** of the related (parent) **HrEvent** row. So

- the first 4 rows of the **EventRating** table have **1** as the value denote the **HrEvent** that has an id of **1** as the parent.
- the last two rows have **2** which denotes the *HrEvent** row that has an id of **2** as the parent.
- the **HrEvent** with an id of **3** has no associated rows in the **EventRating** table.